# SQL Query to get a count where transaction_date is in between first day of the month and last day of the month

Tags: sql, postgresql

PostgreSQL query to retrieve the count of all rows where transaction_date falls between the first day of the current month and the last day of the current month.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE transaction_date BETWEEN (FIRST_DAY_OF_CURRENT_MONTH) AND (LAST_DAY_OF_CURRENT_MONTH);
```

I don't want to compare the transaction_date with any columns in the table. Is there an in-built method to obtain a count of rows for the current month?

Comment: Please do not spam the tag. I have removed all the other database tag except `PostgreSQL`

Comment: Please improve your question and explain what you want to do. Your question as it currently stands doesn't make sense. There is no date which is not between first day and last day of a month.

Comment: Do you want to exclude 1st of month, and last-day of month? or, Just count all occurrences of the current month?

Comment: Why the references to [CURRENT_DATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT)? Are you aware that it always returns current date and time by definition?

Comment: @PaulMaxwell Do you want to exclude 1st of month, and last-day of month? => No,
Count all occurrences of the current month? => Yes

Comment: I understand English may not be your native tongue (neither is mine) but you're asking something that doesn't make the least sense. PostgreSQL, Django... all use the same system clock, and **current date** is never ever going to be in another month, for the same reason that next Wednesday is never going to fall on Sunday. Perhaps you're just asking how to determine if a given date column belongs to current month, albeit in a convoluted way? That's what the answer you already have is answering.

Comment: Apologies, I framed the question incorrectly. I modified the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use date arithmetic to find the first and last day of the current month:

```
... WHERE transaction_date >= date_trunc('month', current_timestamp)::date AND
          transaction_date < (date_trunc('month', current_timestamp) + INTERVAL '1 month')::date
```

Comment: I framed the question incorrectly. I have now revised the question.

Comment: I had anticipated that.